# MVC conditional routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC website and a subdirectory "/dir/" under it which is also configured as an ASP.NET application.

I want the `http://website/dir/` URL to route to a **parent** controller if some condition is met, or simply ignore it and "pass over" to the subdir-application if not. How do I do this?

PS. I cannot use `RouteExistingFiles = true` because both apps have some aspx/ashx/html files that need to work.

Comment: @recursive hostname header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) for this purpose.

Comment: I know, I'm trying it right now, BUT this does not answer the question of how can I pass the request to the subdir-application.

Comment: I think you can combine IgnoreRoute and route with constraint. Write IgnoreRoute first and then register your route with constraint. If your constraint return true, path will be handled by your route otherwise it will be ignored by main application and will be processed by subdir app.

Comment: Tried that, if you ignore the route - its ignored completely, can't be used with conditional forwarding later.

Comment: Yes, you can add constraint to IgnoreRoute as well.

Comment: BTW, if your constraint return false and you don't have any other route for this url, your subdir app will handle the request automatically (i think so) unless you have some wildcard route.

Comment: Your answer still requires `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` but ok, I'll figure something out